# Can I change the default resolution for Hyper-V basic-mode session VMs?

Tags: resolution, hyper-v, vhd

I have to boot fresh VHDs a couple of times a week and every time I change the resolution from the default `1024x768`. For various reasons, I prefer using basic mode VMs, where I suspect Hyper-V is reporting to the guest OS (Windows 10) that the connected screen has this default resolution. Is there a Hyper-V setting that will change this default for future VHDs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No I don't think you can set it from the host side. It completely depends on the guest's request:

[image]

Comment: Is this showing different OSes defaulting to different sizes? Nice.

Comment: @Trillian Yeah Linux requests `1152x864` by default (it's defined in the [`hyperv_fb`](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/drivers/video/fbdev/hyperv_fb.c) driver, and it can be changed by booting with the `video=` kernel parameter. `1024x768` is probably the general default on Windows.